# Why am I not able to insert elements into my linked-list implementation?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am doing linkedlist implementation in java. Particularly, while doing insert operation, if the given index is more than the length of the linkedlist, I have to append the value to the linkedlist. Though I have written code for the same, it is not happening that way.

In order to debug this, I added lines for printing linkedlist. I could print the list just before the condition `if(index >= this.length())` in the insert function but not able to print the linkedlist in the line inside the condition.

```
package com.learning.algorithms.LinkedList;

public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(int i) {
        this.data = i;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

```
package com.learning.algorithms.LinkedList;

public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = new Node();
        this.tail = this.head;
    }

    public LinkedList(int value) {
        this.head = new Node();
        this.head.data = value;
        this.head.next = null;
        this.tail = this.head;
    }

    public LinkedList append(int value) {
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
        this.tail.next = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;

        return this;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node useNode = this.head;

        while(useNode!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(useNode.data);
            useNode = useNode.next;
        }

        //print(useNode);
    }

    private void print(Node useNode) {
        if(useNode!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(useNode.data);
            print(useNode.next);
        }       
    }

    public LinkedList prepend(int i) {
        Node newNode = new Node(i);
        newNode.next = this.head;
        this.head  = newNode;
        return this;
    }

    public LinkedList insert(int index, int value) {
        if(index == 0)
        {
            this.prepend(value);
            return this;
        }

        this.printList();
        if(index >= this.length())
        {
            System.out.println("inside");
            this.printList();
            this.append(value);
            return this;
        }

        Node nodeJustBeforeGivenIndex = this.head;

        // getting node just before given index using while loop
        while(index>1)
        {
            nodeJustBeforeGivenIndex = nodeJustBeforeGivenIndex.next;
            index--;
        }

        // make an insert
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
        newNode.next = nodeJustBeforeGivenIndex.next;
        nodeJustBeforeGivenIndex.next = newNode;

        return this;
    }

    private int length() {
        int counnt = 0;

        if(this.head !=null ) {
            while(this.head !=null )
            {
                this.head = this.head.next;
                counnt++;
            }
        }

        return counnt;
    }
}
```

```
package com.learning.algorithms.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListImplementation {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(10);

        list.append(5);
        list.append(16);
        list.prepend(1);
        list.insert(0, 15);
        list.insert(10, 222);

        list.printList();
    }
}
```

Console output for running this implementation class:

```
15
1
10
5
16
inside
```

Comment: The problem is that you are modifying the head inside length(), after that head is referencing null

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is the dumbest mistake to use head variable to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the head value inside the length method.

This will fix it:

```java
private int length() {
    int counnt = 0;

    Node iter = this.head;
    while(iter !=null )
    {
        iter = iter.next;
        counnt++;
    }

    return counnt;
}
```

Commenting just the two print stamtents inside insert, the output gets to be:

```
inside
15
1
10
5
16
222
```